# Text continues out the right side of input box when using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When entering text into the input box it continues outside the box and can not be seen, you can only see the text you have already written in the box. The text does not go outside the box if I comment out the javascript section so I know it is not a css issue but rather a javascript issue. I could live with it but I am sure other people would complain if they use it.

```js
    var input = document.getElementById("text");
    input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        
        var MessageString = document.querySelector('#text').value;
    
    //      let look = convertToSmilies(MessageString);
    //      var MessageString = look;
    
        input.value = "";
        input.value += MessageString;
    });
```

```css
    div#sendCtrls {
        width: auto;
        margin: 5px auto;
    }
    
    div#sendCtrls input, div#sendCtrls button{
        width: 50%;
        margin: 5px auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
        border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
        padding: 0.625rem;
    }
    div#sendCtrls input:hover, div#sendCtrls button:hover{
        width: 50%;
        margin: 5px auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #FFCCCC;
        padding: 0.625rem;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="sendCtrls">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your message here" id="text">
        <button id="myBtn" style="width: auto;"> Send </button>
    </div>
```

I commented out 2 lines in the JS because it was not needed for testing, it is just a smiley replacer. It will check what is typed in to the input box and if a pattern is matched it will replace the pattern in the input box with a smiley. The issue with text going out of the box is there no matter if those two lines are commented out or not. If I comment out the whole of the JS section the text doesnt go out of the box but then the smiley replacer will not work.

Comment: Hi I can't reproduce your error see here it works fine https://codepen.io/thewhitegrizzzzli/pen/YzWWdvp

Comment: Hmmm that's odd, I am not why? The whole script is too big to post here. I seem to be at a stumbling block with this one.

Comment: can you share a link to this libraryy ill have a lok

Comment: There is no library, it is just everything bundled into 2 php files and a css file, both php files are pretty big.

Comment: yep link works ill load these libs and see what is going on (hopefully haha)

Comment: the problem is in the competition.php file around line 482 onwards, good luck with it, I have been looking at it since 5am this morning and it is now 7pm lol

Comment: hmm the PHP files cut off at the body tag? https://prnt.sc/v2iwcr

Comment: strange, let me look and see what is going on...

Comment: http:/www.finchkeeper.com/downloads/3files.zip  I changed it from a rar to a zip file, maybe this will help? I checked the files and all the content is there

Comment: ok checking now

Comment: I got the full files this time. So what is the code of the index file. The code you posted in your question? Because if I load the 2 PHP files nothing is displayed in the browser

Comment: the file called chatroom.php is the index file. I think I know why it will not load. it works like this, when entering the page chatroom.php it brings up a list from the database with all listed competitions. when you click on one of the items it loads the screen with the template filled with the relevant info of that competition. I think this one I will have to find a fix myself. it would require removing a lot of the php for the parts in question to load up, too much work for a helper

Comment: http:/www.finchkeeper.com/downloads/2files.zip I have a simplified version, this 'should' load up nicely as it does not have all the stuff stopping it from loading. The css file is the same as the other files. the main index or landing page is chatroom.php if you feel you've had enough i will understand :)

Comment: no its fine i rarely have enough lol. i like to go to the very end of the issues and solve them :)

Comment: removing that chunk of js allows the input to work properly but I really need that js as it changes the text to smileys. I have only been programming with javascript for about 3 weeks so sorry if it all looks a bit tatty. have mercy on my little soul lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223314/discussion-between-laurentc-and-charly-willy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can lay this code to rest! The solution was rather simple and needed to replace the lines..

```
   input.value = "";
   input.value += MessageString;
```

with the line..

```
input.value = MessageString;
```

I really hope this solution helps someone who might also be having similar problems.
The final JS code is as follows..

```
var input = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    
    var MessageString = document.querySelector('#text').value;

    let look = convertToSmilies(MessageString);
    var MessageString = look;

    input.value = MessageString;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment these 2 lines of code lines 304 and 305

```
var input = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    
    var MessageString = document.querySelector('#text').value;

//      let look = convertToSmilies(MessageString); //here
//      var MessageString = look;                       //and here

    document.querySelector('#text').value = "";
    document.querySelector('#text').value += MessageString;
});
```

Comment: I have just discovered that this does not work in firefox even after clearing the cache. I do not know why but I can live with it. Tried it on jsfiddle using firefox and got the same problem. I added the function with all the smileys and removed the  // from both lines as mentioned but problem persists. I will do some research and see if this is a firefox issue or just my code. thanks

Comment: hey hmm not really ff is a very important browser, it has to work ideally. let me know if you manage to solve it otherwise ill try to help you

Comment: After spending all night researching and trying out different methods, nothing seems to have any effect. It only happens in firefox. I installed Tor browser which is pretty much the same as firefox and same problem exists. It does not like the text being entered using javascript, that is where the problem stems from for some reason.

Comment: hey Charly, ok but did you install a complete cache clearing effective extension no Ff?

Comment: I mean they usually behave the same so I would be surprised it's raelly an issue? If you told me Opera or Edge then maybe but FF & Chrome usually render mostly the same way

Comment: yes i did clear it completely, spent the day looking for login info for all my sites too lol. I did read on several sites including this one where others had similar issues but their fix was a rather long list of code. It makes me laugh because I wrote the code and I be damned if I know how it works :D

Comment: ok well how did you clear the cache in ff ; did you use an extension like we did with clear cache or just cleared the cache using built-in ff menu?